# Are time zones considered when calculating the Enthusiast badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, activity-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an SE “day”? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)

Are users' local time zones are considered when calculating whether or not to award them the woot!/Enthusiast badge? If not, then which time zone is used in the calculation?

Comment: This question pre-dates the quoted duplicate. "This question covers exactly the same content as earlier questions on this topic." The important word here is "earlier". Why wasn't the duplicate closed?

Answer (score 7):

I find this particularly frustrating. My timezone is UTC+10, so if I visit the site in the morning, but the next day I only visit it in the evening, then a day goes missing from the statistics and thus the woot badge is not awarded - even though I visited the site each day (in my local day).

It's really a bit demoralising...

Answer (score 6):

Since all of SO is in UTC (daily reputation caps etc.), I suspect Enthusiast/Woot badge makes no difference and it is using UTC as well.

Comment: "Enthusiast" :)

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks, corrected the brainfart :)