# What is an SE "day"? When does each day start?

Tags: support, faq, consecutive-days, activity-badges, timezone

When does a day start on the Stack Exchange network?

Some badges (Enthusiast, [Fanatic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fanatic-badge), [Mortarboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7060/badge-for-upvotes-after-rep-cap-is-reached)) and voting limits are bound by and relate heavily to the concept of a day.

Do days correspond to calendar days? What time zone is used?

> #### Related
>
> [Are there any voting limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits)

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

A day starts at 00:00 [UTC time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Marc Gravell explains so in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24884/what-are-the-exact-requirements-for-the-woot-enthusiast-badge/24888#24888) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24884/what-are-the-exact-requirements-for-the-woot-enthusiast-badge).

All times (and timestamps) visible anywhere on Stack Exchange follow this time zone.

You can see the current UTC time from the Notification drop down.

[image]

On Stack Overflow, you can find the drop-down on the top right menu.

[image]

Comment: @ChrisKoknat You've mixed up Standard and Daylight Savings times. Daylight Savings is one hour ahead of standard.

Comment: @ChrisKoknat A Maths problem. During DST it *should* be 6PM PST and 9PM EST. [Learn more about Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).