# What exactly is a "day" in the recent activity area of my "profile"?

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit, recent-activity

I'm not understanding the recent activity date ranges at all. For example, *today* around 12PM I had 105 rep for the day. I was hoping to reach the cap when I got home from work :D but now I click "today" and I've got 25. I don't get it. When I click "Yesterday" it shows me posts from 2 hours ago. That's not yesterday, so that to me is a bug. Unless days are shorter in SO world of course. That's fine, but perhaps they should not be called "today" and "yesterday" if they don't start and end say, oh, around 24 hours apart. If I answered something today, I feel it should be in today, not moved out to yesterday after a few hours.

Comment: i feel sure this is a duplicate, but i'm not finding it.  if it isn't a dupe, it should probably get added to the faq.

Comment: @~quack, this one? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/when-does-a-day-start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Days are defined in UTC.

The day ends at Midnight UTC, more commonly known as:

- 4:00PM PST
- 5:00PM MST
- 6:00PM CST
- 7:00PM EST

Notice these are **Standard Times** not, **Daylight Savings Times**. Therefore if you are in the Pacific Standard Timezone, and you post something at 2PM, at 5PM, it will be considered yesterday.

Comment: Sounds like I have to get up earlier then to reach my daily limit!

Comment: Your times should go in the other direction.

Comment: EST is 5 hours off of GMT, so 7 or 8 pm EST is the changeover.

Comment: @Lance Sorry, didn't clearly understand your comment.

Comment: This may explain why I've missed out on getting the fanatic badge on SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux/unix/osx

```
$ TZ=utc date
```

Will give you the time of day in UTC

Comment: I searched for how to do this at the command line in Windows (*sacrelige!*), as I was curious, and got a SO post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-usi