# What is a day on SO?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit, timezone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When does a day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/when-does-a-day-start)

So, today I reached my rep cap for the day, but I have no idea what a day is? When does it start and finish, in what time-zone?

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow's standard time is [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC).

You can see the current time on your notifications page.

Comment: UTC is essentially CET, it's not GMT, The notifications page shows a from to date, the latter being 6 hours behind my time, which is not UTC or GMT. I'm 10 hours ahead?

Comment: @Pulse according to http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=261 you are 11 hours ahead at the moment. Does that make more sense? For what it's worth, the "day" on the notification page is always totally off, I don't know the rules behind that. But the "important" things - vote count reset, reputation limit - are reset at 0:00 UTC.