# Stackoverflow claims I broke my consecutive visit streak - I know I didn't

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I'm not sure if this is inappropriate, but I have been tracking my visits to stackoverflow for the past 2 months and according to the website I broke my streak 2 days ago. I know this not to be true; what do you suppose could have happened?

What exactly counts as a "visit"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an SE "day"? When does each day start?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consecutive visit streak is counted as follows:

- At least 1 visit on each **UTC** day
- Activity, whose exact definition is unknown, save that it requires more than just 1 main page visit

Comment: That UTC thing is a real bastard if you're in a timezone that's extremely one way or the other (I'm +10 (+11 in DST)) - it's easy to miss a "day" by accident