# Potential Server Issue for Fanatic/Enthusiast?

Tags: support, badges, consecutive-days, activity-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consecutive days problem #97?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97)

I have been working on my fanatic badge for right around 54 days. Over the weekend, 11th-15th, I visited daily. As I got my 30 consecutive days a few weeks ago, I've been making sure to visit the site plenty. So I know I did not miss the 12th, but as of today (tonight, even, I believe), my SO profile says I did not visit the site on 5/12/2012. Here is my profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231943/davek804

Has there been a server issue as is discussed in these posts:

[Lost consecutive days status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67191/lost-consecutive-days-status)
[Stackoverflow claims I broke my consecutive visit streak - I know I didn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/stackoverflow-claims-i-broke-my-consecutive-visit-streak-i-know-i-didnt)

?
Is there anything that can be done? What about a screenshot of my history (lets hope I haven't cleaned it...)?

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a modicum of activity(not just logging in)--I've found that a few votes/comments do the trick, and of course a post takes care of the activity as well.

You have no posts/comments for May 10 - May 14, looking at your  [activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231943/davek804?tab=activity&sort=all)
[image]

Check [your votes tab and see if you have any activity those days](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231943/davek804?tab=votes&sort=all) (that tab, along with your days-visited info is private and hidden to all except you)