# What is the "daily reputation cap"?

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

This is really a mystery for me.  What is the "daily reputation cap" that is required to get Epic, Legendary, and Mortarboard badges?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you reach +200 reputation in one day you will get Mortarboard.

And 50 days of 200+ reputation gives you Epic.

Comment: Note: Epic and Legendary include days where you get *exactly* 200 rep

Comment: What's "one day"? Midnight to midnight in my time zone? Or in Pacific/Eastern Standard Time?

Comment: @xjcl see [What is an SE “day”? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27199/226705). TLDR: all in UTC.

Answer (score 52):

> You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given [day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start). Accepted answers and bounties are counted separately ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/)). Reputation "lost" from the reputation cap is not awarded on following days.)

This is from the [Reputation FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

You can find out whether you've hit the reputation cap. Look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation) for instructions:

> Make sure you are logged in, and visit
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/reputation
> https://serverfault.com/reputation
> https://superuser.com/reputation
> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation

So at the end of the reputation report you find a section like this:

[image]

So for getting the badges you need to accumulate the right amount of days you hit 200+ reputation.

Comment: Oh this explains why I got >200 reputation today... I didn't know the rep cap only included upvotes and edits!