# Bugs in the reputation tab

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

I've spotted two potential problems with the reputation tab, I hope both are documented on the image below:

[image: reputation tab of a user]

First of all, there seems to be a **off-by-one** error. If september 24 is selected (in gray), The list underneath it shows +20 (which was, as the tooltip advices), the reputation of the day before. This behavior is spotted on all days. Perhaps it depends on the user's time zone. For me this is *Central European Time (CET)* (mentioning this for debugging purposes).

Furthermore as the image shows, removed posts are shown as well. This however results in the fact that the [reputation cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63327/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap) is no longer taken into account. The total reputation for that day is `480`, but this is partly realized with a post that was later removed. This is perhaps more a discussion on whether to take the reputation cap into account.

Comment: I think it is not a full duplicate. Especially because of the second argument. But no problem to close this one.

Comment: To answer your other question about removed posts, it is that that way by-design.