# My Stack Overflow consecutive days have been reset to 1

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I see there are lots of posts about this in the past, but I wasn't able to find any recent ones (it may be my failure at searching).

I've been visiting every day to work up to the Fanatic badge. I'm not just loading my account page, but I'm also clicking around, viewing some questions, and sometimes answers a few.

I was on Stack Overflow yesterday (the 31st) and saw that my consecutive days had dropped to 1, even though the consecutive days calendar showed that I had been active every day for the last eight days. I even posted answers on the 31st (*[Connecting to a MySQL database using Xcode and Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858274/xcode-objective-c-connect-to-mysql-database/4858371#4858371)*), but it's not showing that I was active on that day.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Related: *[What is an SE “day”? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you check the timestamp of your answer, you'll note that it says `2011-02-01 02:42:45Z`. While for you, it may have been still the 31st, in GMT (which is what Stack Overflow looks at and what the badge measures days in) it was already February 1st.

If that's the only activity you can cite for your January 31st, then it was already too late, unfortunately.

Comment: The calendar shouldn't show activity though. @Kenny Are you sure the calendar shows you as active on the 31st?

Comment: @Michael I judged that, from Kenny's third paragraph's last sentence, that the calendar was blank for the 31st.

Comment: *sigh* Thanks, Grace. Yes, my first interaction with SO was at 4:15pm PST, which means I missed the window by like 15 minutes. Thanks.