# The Ethereum Stack Exchange site says I wasn't here yesterday, but I was

Tags: support, achievements-dialog, consecutive-days

I know it’s not a big deal in the grand scheme of issues, but I have been diligently coming every day to be consistent and work towards those achievements and now my days visited have been reset to 1 because the website didn't recognize I was here.

I was logged in, as I always am, and I was here for a while.

I am not sure if anything can be done about this since it’s a non issue to most, but I’d like to collect my achievements since I am working towards them.

[image]

Comment: Visit days are based on UTC time, not local time. I'm currently in UTC-7 time, which means that if I visit a site earlier than 17:00 on a given day and then visit after 17:00 the next day, it will lead to an un-visited day.

Comment: Something similar also happend to me once. I opened Stack Overflow once, but it didn’t count as a visit. This is likely because your browser displayed a cached version of the site but didn’t actually make a server request.

Comment: There must be better duplicates. FAQ entry: *[What is an SE "day"? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/)*. Some leads: *[My Stack Overflow consecutive days have been reset to 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77390/)*, *[I broke my visited streak. Why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79219/)*, and *[How do I know whether I am eligible for the Fanatic badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175412/)* (*"you have to actually be active on the site for it to count towards the badge* ***not just load the front page"***).