# I broke my visited streak. Why?

Tags: support, consecutive-days

How did this happen? Just yesterday I had 73 consecutive visits, and now I got one. What time zone are you using?

[image]

My participation just dropped by a 98%.

Comment: Seriously... it's just a badge...

Comment: Badges?  Badges!  We don't need to stinkin' badges!

Comment: I think "So long fanatic badge. and SO" means you're the opposite of a fanatic

Comment: "My participation just dropped by a 98%." yeah, sometimes the rules of the game are annoying, but I can certainly understand why you might be disenchanted with a game whose rules you don't fully understand.  Hopefully you'll find something that suits your needs and interests better.

Comment: Don't let this keep you from contributing.  I can see from [your SO profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/410273/andrewk) that you have contributed some questions and answers to the site.  It's not a bad thing to not have the Fanatic badge, and most importantly, you can still earn it :)  Keep in mind what the FAQ says about Gold Badges:  `Gold Badges are rare. You’ll have to actively work toward these. They’re something of an accomplishment!`  They're tough to get, but if you keep contributing and working towards a goal, you can get some gold badges :)

Comment: Related: *[What is an SE “day”? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199)*

Comment: The [badge page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) states clearly how the days are counted. If you really want to get a badge, first figure out how it works.

Answer (score 13):

Everything resets at 0 GMT. You'll need to visit once per GMT day.

For instance, visiting at 8pm EST and then again at 8am EST the next day will not count as both days, as they both occur on the same GMT day.

On the other hand, visiting at 8am EST in the morning, and then 8pm EST in the evening on the same day will count as two separate days. So you can, in fact, get the fanatic badge visiting every other 'day'.

But yeah, in general time zone problems can cause this.  If it's really very disappointing, email team at stack overflow and plead your case.  You may or may not receive sympathy, but it's pretty much your only option at this point.

Comment: That, or visit for 100 more days. Just pin a tab in your browser or something if you care that much! :)

Comment: Of course real fanatics don't even try to get this badge.  It chases them down and embeds itself in their flesh.

Comment: @Polyanna, I think your last sentence should actually read "You may or may not receive sympathy, but it's pretty much all you're likely to receive" :)