# What timezone is used on SE sites?

Tags: support, timestamps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When does a day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/when-does-a-day-start)

What timezone is used to calculate daily reputation, caps  etc ?

When "today" will be yesterday?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Coordinated Universal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), or UTC Time, is used to determine dates on Stack Exchange. You can see the current UTC time by hovering over the arrow next to your username at the top of each page – a window appears with the UTC Time at the bottom-left.