# Timezones and mentions of days/weeks/months for badges and elsewhere

Tags: support, badges, timezone, culture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an SE “day”? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)

I just wondered if things like the rules for badges *get +200 rep in one day*, and the displays of rep per day/week/month took into account timezones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, insofar as they all obey "StackExchange Standard Time", which happens to bear a strong resemblance to UTC.

Comment: Sorry, don't quite follow. Are you saying that if i gained 200 rep in one day according to a timezone offset from UTC, it doesn't follow that i gained 200 rep according to the UTC timezone, therefore i wouldn't get the badge? (note in my case this is pretty much ok as i'm on GMT).

Comment: If you gain 200 rep in one "SE day" (defined as 0000-2359 UTC) then you get the badge.

Comment: Ok, that's the answer i was after.