# Something is wrong with the visited date?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an SE “day”? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)

I remember i have checked my profile yesterday and it was showing visited days as 11 consecutive days.
today i have checked and its showing 1 consecutive day.
I have seen this things many times but I was busy so i didn't notice this and i didn't raise this in meta.

It's not showing data as i have accepted. today it should be 12 consecutive days. May be its problem with the timezone difference.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the missing days by clicking on <kbd>X days, 1 consecutive</kbd>, I bet you'll be missing yesterday, because if you click on the network less than Y times, visit for that day doesn't count (Where Y is an unknown number of times you have to click before visit counts)

Comment: I know this thing. it's showing yesterday i didn't visit SO. I am very much sure that i have visited SO yesterday.

Comment: @Vivart: and how long were you browsing around it?

Comment: @Vivart: Remember that days are measured in UTC time, not your local time zone.

Comment: you can see that i am a member of SO since 705 days. before today i was not serious with consecutive days statics. but i have seen this thing many times, i used to check SO every day and this counter reset itself dont know when?

Comment: @Vivart: I ask how long were you browsing around SO yesterday

Comment: yesterday was sunday, so i was not browsing SO for problem solving. i used to open http://stackexchange.com/ and i have seen some hot question on SO and i read those question. so i don't remember exact time but i was on SO for 5-10 minutes.

Comment: @Vivart: and do you remember what time was that ? What is your timezone?

Comment: hmmmm i think around 2 pm. it was after noon (gmt +5.5 india)IST