# Enthusiast badge calculation?

Tags: support, badges, consecutive-days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an SE “day”? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)

I don't work on Sundays, as a religious conviction, so I thought there wasn't any way for me to win the "Enthusiast" badge.

I was okay with that as I know that most badges are attainable, but the idea isn't to have all of them attainable for everyone.  I just figured I'd work towards other badges.

However, to my surprize and enjoyment, I found that although I'm on SO every other day and often at night, I somehow got to 29 days without logging in on Sundays?  How is this calculation done?

Comment: It's almost certainly a result of Stack Overflow measuring a "day" by UTC time, rather than by your local time. So when you logged in on what you thought was Saturday or Monday, SO's servers actually saw it as Sunday.

Comment: According to your profile, you are in Missouri. Badge calculations, like almost everything on Stack Exchange sites, define a "day" by UTC time. It's possible for you to log in on Saturday night (your time) and vote/post/comment in a way that gets recorded as Sunday (SE time). Congratulations on the extra-meaningful Enthusiast badge!

Comment: Okay, I didn't wasn't aware of the UTC time calculation.  Please put it as an answer to get credit and thanks for the info!

Comment: Since when did playing on SO count as work anyway? :-)

Comment: The way I view it, anything related to what I do in my regular job, I consider work.  That being said, my part time hobby became my full-time job back in 1999.  Being on SO is one of the perks of the job!