# Should I not be seeing my reputation activity in my own timezone?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, timezone

Shown here is a snap of reputation activities, note the words today & yesterday. Its already half past midnight for me, so what is shown as "**today**" should have been shown as "**yesterday**"! This definitely is not in my time-zone! In fact I do NOT see an option of setting my time-zone in my SO profile!

```
 18    today
+10    18 hours ago    upvote
+2     7 hours ago     edit  
+2     8 hours ago     edit
+2     12 hours ago    accept
+2     13 hours ago    edit  

 31    yesterday
+20    20:34    2 events
+5     14:10    upvote  
+2     20:24    edit  
+2     19:43    edit
+2     06:32    edit
```

I wanted to post a picture of this to better explain, but I am not allowed to post images!

Comment: Allowing users to set their timezones will be a good thing. I'm sure Stack code is flexible enough to accommodate that...

Comment: Within 3 minutes this question went from created to open to closed and back to open, with the right answer! :)

Comment: Welcome to [metase] :) You'll get to know soon, this is not same as other SO sites. Read the [faqs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), and other highly voted questions about how [metase] works.

Comment: @Curious Yeah, I closed it as a duplicate first, but then changed my mind.

Answer (score 9):

This is by design. We use [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) instead of individual user-specific timezones.

You can read more here: [What is an SE "day"? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start).

Answer (score 1):

It's better to have a common time/day system for all users as the users of SO and all child sites are located globally. Getting this feature is not a huge technical task, but there is no hard and fast use-case to this.

Hope you understand.

Comment: @Curious mtk says it's *not* a huge task, and indeed the technical side would  be relatively easy. But imagine the chaos that would ensue - you would no longer have consistent rankings (eg. when doing daily or weekly leagues), support requests concerning rep calculation would become a nightmare because everyone is in a different time zone, the rep cap would have to be calculated on a per-time zone basis.... it's just an insane amount of complexity and new problems for no good reason.

Comment: A client side script can easily convert the UTC times to logged in user's timezone and render the pages accordingly.

Comment: @Pekka -thanks for pointing out my mistake in reading mtk's answer (I have removed that comment). Regarding your comment, all the times can be stored in SE servers in UTC (that's what everyone does), a client side script (which would run in the user's browser) and covert the times in user's timezone and display the pages. All leagues etc. can still run fine, because the server would still store the times in UTC...

Comment: @Curious fair enough, if all the calculation stuff would still be in UTC, I suppose a script could easily change the dates. That could be a job for a 3rd party userscript.

Comment: @Pekka Why 3rd party when the first part (SE) is so good...

Comment: @all I agree with all the points given by Pekka's Comment.

Comment: @Curious We (SE) are pretty happy with UTC at this point, so if you really want to see things in your own timezone sooner rather than later, your own userscript would be the way to go. :)