# Timezone Problems

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, timezone

I've been using Stack Overflow for a while and I noticed that for me, the time is 7 hours ahead of my actual time. I live in Calgary AB, Canada so I might get something different, but the next day is shown at 5:00pm for me. I was wondering if there could be a PHP function that instead of using the `date_default_timezone_set` function (I'm not completely sure you use this but it's evident you do), you could use some form of the `timezone_offset_get` function. This of course, does not have to apply for everyone, but can apply to some people.

Comment: What are you actually asking for here?

Comment: You know how the calendar switches from day to day? Mine will switch to Monday in 1 hour even though it's only gonna be 5:00.

Comment: Why is this a problem? I'm not trying to be funny or sarcastic, but I'm trying to understand what it is you really want. (BTW, Stack Exchange uses .NET not php)

Comment: All time on SO/SE is based on UTC time. That determines the start and end of days for everyone.

Comment: It's not as much of a feature request as it is a bug. Do you know how at 12:00 am, the calendar shows a new day, and all of the user restrictions for up votes and down votes are reset?

Comment: It's not a bug. All time used is UTC. This is by design.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13435/use-users-timezone-for-vote-limit-reputation-cap-badges-etc and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/make-recent-activity-today-etc-buttons-based-on-users-time-zone and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145581/should-i-not-be-seeing-my-reputation-activity-in-my-own-timezone

Comment: I said I lived in Calgary AB, Canada though. That's the thing

Comment: Wonderful. Go skate some laps on the great olympic oval for me. It doesn't change a thing though. It's the same for everybody by design. My local time is not UTC either. It's an hour off. All by design.

Comment: Sorry about that guys

Comment: No need to be sorry. It can be confusing at first. But as Anna says, it's all for a reason. You'll get used to it.

Comment: One quick example of why a shared time is a good idea: you can get a list of the top users for the current week. Would it seem fair if for some people that week started 12 hours earlier than for others?

Answer (score 4):

We're running on UTC time by design. I can appreciate the occasional confusion this causes, but keeping things on just one timezone is more straightforward in the long run. Jon Skeet goes into some of the reasons why [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13437/155160).

You can see the current UTC time by hovering over your user name in the top bar on any page of the site.