# How does day roll over on SO?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an SE “day”? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)

Can someone please explain when and how the "day" rolls over in SO? In other words, what exactly is a "day" according to the site in regards to reputation and other important things that need a "daily" count? I missed a 200 rep day by 12 rep because the day rolled over, but at 2:10pm local time (Hawaii). Does the day roll over at 00:00 UTC or is there some other definition? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It rolls at 00:00 UTC, as you guessed.

Comment: Thanks. There must be some client-side delay or something to make it appear to roll over at 00:10 today for me. Weird. Thanks!