# What time zone does the question time stamp refer to?

Tags: support, timezone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an SE “day”? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)

According to the question [What is an SE “day”? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start), Stack Overflow's servers are on UTC time. Does the time stamp for when a question or answer is posted match this time zone? Or are the time stamps localized somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All timestamps on Stack Exchange websites are in UTC.

No localization to other timezones takes place.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I'll accept this as soon as I'm able.