# Calendar Month of Current Day - New Year

Tags: bug, profile-page, calendar

It should be January 1st, 2013 now by UTC. When I go to my profile and click on the `X days, Y consecutive` text, I see the calendar for December, not January:

[image]

It's marking my visited dates (and January 1) fine. Doesn't the calendar usually jump to the month of the [current day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)? Why is it still December 31st, 2012? Does this happen every New Year?

Comment: I see January. What's your local time? Did you clear caches and forced a reload?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using yesterday's technology?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh okay, in my local time it's still 12/31. Case closed? I thought everything on SE is in UTC though. I did clear my cache.

Comment: All the dates are in UTC, but the date picker just picks the current (local) date by default since it's client side. It's minor, but it should probably move to the current UTC date for consistency.