# How do I know whether I am eligible for the Fanatic badge?

Tags: support, badges

I visit Stack Overflow every day, even on weekends. I have been using Stack Overflow for almost two years now. It's somehow become an addiction for me.

But I've never received the [fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/83/fanatic) badge.

How can I find out whether I'm eligible for this badge or not?

See my [SO profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650722/mohsen).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your profile, there is a visits count that displays the total number of days visited and the consecutive days visited as well.

[image: Consecutive Days on Site]

Once you have reached 100 consecutive days you will receive the fanatic badge. As a note, you have to actually be active on the site for it to count towards the badge not just load the front page.

Answer (score 6):

You can track your consecutive visits on your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650722/mohsen). If you click on the "visited" line, you'll even see a handy little calendar pop-up.

Keep in mind that Stack Exchange [servers run on UTC time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start) and not your local timezone, and that just opening the front page isn't enough to register a "visit".

Comment: Wait, opening the front page isn't enough to register a visit? What *does* register a visit? That really ought to be explained better in this badge -- I've never seen the term "visit" on the web mean anything but "page hit".

Comment: @BenLee For the purposes of the badge, we want you to do a bit more than just mechanically open the front page and close it again.

Comment: Okay, but what is required? (And I think the term "visited" is a real misnomer in this case)

Comment: Just for the record, I never tried to gain this badge, especially not by just hitting the front page, I'm just really curious now.

Comment: @BenLee Visit a few of the questions on the front page and give some upvotes to good questions/answers. That will be plenty to get the badge. Plus you wouldnt be much of a fanatic if you were just loading the front page and left right :P

Comment: @JoshMein, I'm not trying to get the badge, I'm trying to understand what "visited" is supposed to mean in this context.

Comment: You need to interact with the site in some way. Look at a question, vote, comment, answer, review, edit ... if you're called to a site by an inbox notification, do something else too. If you load the front page to see what's happening, do something else too. Simple.

Comment: @BenLee I don't want to give out the exact details for the same reason that just opening the front page and not doing anything doesn't really count. Basically, just visit stack overflow and use the site like you normally would for 100 days in a row. :)

Comment: Okay. That makes complete sense for a badge, I just think "visited" is the wrong language. Should probably say "use stack overflow for 100 consecutive days". "Use" is much more vague, which is appropriate here. Anyway, I'd raise it up in another meta question but I doubt it's worth it, that would be splitting hairs.