# Reputation not showing properly

Tags: support, reputation

I am having issue with my reputations.

[How do I find elements in array with another indexes array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763551/how-do-i-find-elements-in-array-with-another-indexes-array/17763560#17763560) earned +65,but it is showing +55.

[How do I create a custom “merge” method for hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766255/how-do-i-create-a-custom-merge-method-for-hashes/17766277#17766277) earned +40 but showing +32

[Hash to custom array implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766823/hash-to-custom-array-implementation) earned +20,nothing is being displayed.

Comment: Congratulations on hitting the repcap.

Comment: @Mysticial so what should I do now?

Comment: Nothing. It's normal. Do it enough times and you'll get a nice, shiny badge. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations! You've reached the daily reputation cap. You can only gain 200 points from upvotes in a single day.

[What is reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. Only [bounty awards](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/bounty) and [accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/accepted-answer) are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

And on the meta [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/194906), it also says:

> You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given [day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start). Accepted answers and bounties are counted separately ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/)). Reputation "lost" from the reputation cap is not awarded on following days.

Comment: ok.. but I can see from my activity tracker.. before also I crossed +200 2 times.. I didn't get anything.. :(

Comment: when should I get the extra rep?

Comment: @Priti Yes you did, you [got the mortarboard badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard?userid=2140372)

Comment: @Priti You don't get the rep back. I think it's designed to stop you staying up all day and all night trying to increase your rep.

Comment: OMG!! My all effort has lost.. :)))

Comment: @Priti Think of it as being so awesome you went off the top of the scale / hit maximum speed / were so tall you touched the ceiling. If you do it 50 times, you get the Epic badge. 150 times would be Legendary.

Comment: thanks for letting me know... :) I will keep it in mind..