# On reputation section: all vote values are not shown for each event

Tags: support, reputation, voting, profile-page

I just reviewed a reputation for some users and I found that all vote values are not shown for some events, I don't know if this is a bug or just normal behavior, I didn't found any information about it.

As shown in the screen-shot, vote value is not shown for some upvote events.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely the user has hit the daily reputation cap. Once a user receives 200 reputation points from votes and edits they can't get any of the same reputation until UTC 00:00.

See: [What is reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. Only [bounty awards](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/bounty) and [accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/accepted-answer) are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

See also this [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/194906):

> You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given [day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start). Accepted answers and bounties are counted separately ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/)). Reputation "lost" from the reputation cap is not awarded on following days.

Answer (score 0):

Upvotes on Community Wiki posts don't give reputation, so none is shown.

Comment: Looks more like repcap than wiki.

Comment: @Mystical, good call.

Comment: Yes, I checked some of them, some of them Wiki but not all