# Where can I find how many delete votes I have left?

Tags: feature-request, support, vote-to-delete

Oddly enough, I just cannot find this question asked anywhere else! I searched on meta, did a custom google search, checked [the FAQ on deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/), looked everywhere on the site itself; I found nothing.

How can I check how many delete (and undelete) votes I have left?

**Edit:** added [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag - apparently it is not possible to do this. I would suggest making the delete dialog the same kind of popup as the close vote and flag dialogs, but it doesn't matter how it's done, really. I do think that using the same popups would be more consistent though.

Comment: A more specific request - [Can we display the users' remaining votes when voting to delete?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204428/can-we-display-the-users-remaining-votes-when-voting-to-delete)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed); you can see how many in the popup for confirming deletion:

[image: screenshot]

I would still prefer a dialog like the close vote one, but meh.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a running count of available delete votes shown anywhere in the UI. Same as with comment votes.

I presume this is because delete votes were initially unlimited for users with the requisite privileges. They were only capped after the Summer of Love, because if I've learned anything about love, it is that it often involves sacrifices you aren't sure that you want to make.

I guess you just have to resort to the manual method: count how many you've used during the day and subtract it from your known total allotment. If you lose count, you can check the [list of deletion votes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1223693/doorknob?tab=votes&sort=deletion) in your profile (votes → deletion). Naturally, this is a list of votes for all time—you'll have to narrow it down to just the ones you've cast within [a Stack Exchange day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start).