# Can we display the users' remaining votes when voting to delete?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

Can we display the **user**'s remaining votes in the vote to delete dialog box?

Dialog box in Chrome:

[image]

I'm **not** talking about the **post**'s remaining votes before deleted, which can be seen when hovering over <kbd>delete</kbd>.

[image]

So similar to the count that can be seen in the close vote dialog box:

[image]

Comment: Why should the count of needed votes have influence on your decision to vote or not to vote? Or is this just out of curiosity, which I could empathize.

Comment: @bummi The count of needed votes is already displayed (as per the second image), I'd like to see how many votes I have remaining for the day (similar to what is done on the close vote dialog box).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This *feature* is deployed as of build rev `2013.11.27.1179` on sites; `2013.11.27.1686` on meta

Comment: Awesome, but small problem - it caches (I presume). I was on 13 delete votes remaining up to my very last delete vote. Will post a bug or new request if required.

Comment: I see the problem now - presumably it loads the delete vote count when loading the page, so it's a bit of a problem when ones has multiple tabs / pages open. But much less significant than I first thought, not sure how difficult it would be to change / fix.