# Number of deletion votes required is shown wrong

Tags: support, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

I went on to delete a few posts today from the 10k tools page. I noticed the following bug when using [the `delete` button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/391240/1190388):

1. I'm merely hovering over the button. Haven't clicked it yet.

   > [image: Just hovering]
2. Clicking it shows the following `alert` box:

   > [image: High alert]
3. Afterwards, on selecting OK from the previous section; you'd see this:

   > [image: yay for algebra]

On viewing the page source; you'd see this HTML:

```
<a
    href="#"
    id="delete-post-391240"
    title="You voted to delete. 2 more votes from other users are needed to delete this post."
    class=""
    data-delete-prompt="Vote to delete this post? (10 votes remaining)"
    data-undelete-prompt="Vote to undelete this post? (13 votes remaining)">
        delete (2)
</a>
```

Did I do something wrong in my basic algebra?

Comment: Interesting bug.

Comment: What is the bug? What do you expect to be different? I probably miss the point...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't one extra delete vote required every 10 upvotes? There are 10 upvotes and 2 downvotes on the question.

Comment: @rene But, but... but! I used the hand-made red circle thingies...

Comment: @hjpotter92 The *10 votes remaining* means *you* have 10 remaining delete votes.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I think so, but I wouldn't know which count to believe with a conflict in numbers like this.

Comment: @hjpotter92 ok, ok, have my upvote...

Comment: @Stijn Ah, I see. Any documentation?

Comment: Is that html there after you voted to delete? That could be a potential bug if you could 'load' a new question to delete without a full server roundtrip.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yes, I've just found documentation, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 10 votes remaining means you have 10 remaining delete votes.

Here's the feature request for the implementation of this: [Can we display the users' remaining votes when voting to delete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204428/can-we-display-the-users-remaining-votes-when-voting-to-delete)

Comment: The wordings should be clearer. >.<