# Delete vote confirmation dialog displays incorrect remaining vote count

Tags: bug, status-declined, vote-to-delete

When I vote to delete a question, the confirmation dialog states that I have 2 votes remaining:

[image]

When I choose "OK", however, the vote limit error pops up:

[image]

I can confirm, from my profile, that I have cast 13 delete votes today; the displayed count in the error is correct.

I have 18,325 rep on that site and therefore, according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105876/230261) (assuming that answer is still up-to-date), I should have 5 (base) + 8 (rep) = 13 delete votes. That implies the error message itself is deserved.

Therefore, the dialog is incorrect, and I do not have 2 votes remaining.

Comment: @Shokhet It's reproducible. I don't remember but I'm 99.99% sure I had multiple tabs open (it fits with my usual pattern of opening multiple tabs for questions I want to review, e.g. the 10k delete list I was looking at at the time) and the description is correct, and that  was most likely the cause. Using that I can reproduce it consistently. It's declined because it's not worth fixing.

Comment: In other words, by-design. [This was observed earlier](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204428/can-we-display-the-users-remaining-votes-when-voting-to-delete?rq=1#comment670738_209171), btw.

Comment: @Woodface No, not by-design, and not no-repro, just plain old declined. Jeez, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can reproduce this is by having a page open in one time and running out of delete votes in another tab. These counts and tooltips are determined when the page is rendered, so it's possible for them to go out of date.

Considering that we still check server-side and no extra votes end up being granted, I'm okay with that.

Comment: I don't remember for sure, but it's very possible that I had multiple tabs open. I just tried it right now and saw the same thing. I also agree that it's not a big deal since it's just the dialog box.

Comment: Currently, you can also reproduce it when voting multiple to delete multiple times on the *same* page - the count does not get updated. If it was stored in Javascript, it would be trivial to do something like `count--` on delete, but it looks like the alert text, including the count, is simply retrieved from the HTML, `<a href="#" data-delete-prompt="Vote to delete this post? (21 votes remaining)"`

Comment: Yes, this is still an issue in situations like the one mentioned by @CertainPerformance