# Meaning of "votes remaining" in close vote dialog

Tags: support, vote-to-close

When I vote to close a question, the pop up window shows `39 votes remaining`. Does this mean I have 39 vote remaining for today?

Answer (score 5):

It means that you have 39 close votes remaining for the day. You can only vote to close as many times as you have close votes remaining.

This is unrelated to the number of votes you have remaining for questions and answers.

[A Stack Overflow day starts at 00:00 UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start). This is when all of your votes (including close votes) will reset.