# Close Vote Regeneration

Tags: support, vote-to-close

When I vote to close a question, there's a message saying that I have X votes left. I assume those regenerate after some time? What are the rules on that? Is it different for different sites across the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes)

Comment: @RobertColumbia Just FYI, editing the automatic comment will prevent it from being automatically deleted once the question is closed. While I don't always agree with the new form of comment, I avoid editing it for this reason unless I'm making a more substantive edit to explain how exactly it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Closed votes around the day are determined, and vary depending on the site.

- [Cast close and reopen votes - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

  > You may cast up to **24** close votes per day.
- [Cast close and reopen votes - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

  > You may cast up to **50** close votes per day.

Comment: Do they vary per site or based on previous activity? I know that for flags the cap rises the more helpful flags you've cast (from 20 to 100 from memory).

Comment: @Mast No, you can't do anything to raise your close vote quota.

Comment: Relevant for "per day": https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start