# Numbers on stats don't match the number of reviews completed

Tags: support, review, review-stats

I'll try to be brief. It's not a big deal but it does seem odd and I can't find a logical explanation.

On English Language for Learners I reviewed a couple of questions on the **close votes** queue, I didn't get beyond two because the queue was cleared. As you can see in the screenshot below, it says I have reviewed two posts. The subsequent user reviewed nine questions.

[image]

However, this seemed strange to me because I was used to seeing more than 11 questions in the review queue. I checked the history page and I saw that the moderator had reviewed far more than nine questions in the last 24 hours. Some questions were closed, some left open and others were edited.

> > [image: screenshot of ELL History page showing 18 reviews completed]

According to the history page, the last [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/249017/took-action-on-in-recycling) was reviewed (left open) 19 hours ago.

---

### Why don't the stats match the history page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stats count from 0:00 UTC, not the last 24 hours; my colleague Eddie has made 9 reviews since then (the red line below indicates 0:00 UTC):

[image]

To confirm, you can either manually subtract 10 hours from the current UTC timestamp (which is shown in the achievements dialog):

[image]

or, more conveniently, as so often with dates/timestamps on Stack Exchange, hover over the (now) 11 hours ago; a tooltip will tell you the timestamp of the event in UTC.

[image]

Comment: How can an ordinary user (e.g. someone who is not a developer) tell when it is 0:00 UTC (Coordinated Universal Time)?

Comment: UTC is... kinda "standard" - Its based off GMT. Not "easy" but you can look up the conversion. For me, I am on GMT +8 for example.

Comment: @Mari-LouA it is called an [SE day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start) but they could have picked any timezone to count as "start".

Comment: @Mari-LouA good question, there are some built-in tricks for this, see the updated answer.