# What does "UTC time" refer to in the "Achievements" dropdown?

Tags: support, time, timezone

In the "Achievements" dropdown, I see a clock labeled "UTC time".

[image: Dropdown with text "ACHIEVEMENTS UTC TIME 04:45]

I want to know what "UTC time" refers to, and whether is it different from a normal clock.  If it differs from a normal clock, how does it differ?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Comment: What do you mean with 'normal clock'? It's hard to tell if it differs and how if you don't include that information. And if this is about SE, could you clarify that by editing your post to at least include where you saw 'UTC time'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the "UTC time" indicator in the achievements drop-down menu.

UTC is [Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (also known, for most intents and purposes, as Greenwich Mean Time), and it's the time zone the Stack Exchange network runs on.

For example, many things, such as the daily 200-reputation cap and daily vote limits, are reset each new day at 00:00 UTC.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start